# You need to specify a parseClassName for the PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

I created a tableViewcontroller and assigned it the custom class: `PFQueryTableViewController` in story board. I then also gave it the `parseClassName "userMessage"` and for some reason when i try to run the application I always get the same error message: `NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'You need to specify a parseClassName for the PFQueryTableViewController.`
I dont understand why I am getting this error because I explicitly gave the class a parseClassName.

Here is my associated code for the PFQueryTabletableViewController:

`import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import Parse`

`class TableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {`

```
let userMessages = ["blah blahh blahhh", "Beep Beep Boop", "Beep Beep Bobbity boop"]

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var currLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D?

override init!(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, className: className)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    self.parseClassName = "userMessage"
    self.textKey = "text"
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
    self.objectsPerPage = 40

}





private func alert(message: String){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Uh-OH", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
    let settings = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {(action) -> Void in
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
        return

    }

    alert.addAction(settings)
    alert.addAction(action)
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 120
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 120
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = 100
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    alert("Cannot fetch your location!!")
}

override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery! {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Messages")
    if let queryLoc = currLocation {
        query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: PFGeoPoint(latitude: queryLoc.latitude, longitude: queryLoc.longitude), withinMiles: 1)
        query.limit = 40
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    }else {
        query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: PFGeoPoint(latitude: 37.41182, longitude: -121.941125), withinMiles: 1)
        query.limit = 40
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    }

    return query
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    if(locations.count > 0) {
        let location = locations[0] as CLLocation
        println(location.coordinate)
        currLocation = location.coordinate
    } else {
        alert("Cannot fetch your loation")
    }
}

override func objectAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> PFObject! {
    var obj : PFObject? = nil
    if(indexPath.row < self.objects.count) {
        obj = self.objects[indexPath.row] as? PFObject
    }
    return obj
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return userMessages.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TableViewCell
    cell.messageText.text = object.valueForKey("text") as? String
    cell.messageText.numberOfLines = 0
    let views = object.valueForKey("count") as Int
    cell.numberOfViewsLabel.text = "\(views)"
    cell.numberOfViewsLabel.text = "\((indexPath.row + 1) * 5)"
    return cell
}

func addToViews(sender: AnyObject) {
    let hitPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    let hitIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint)
    let object = objectAtIndexPath(hitIndex)
    object.incrementKey("count")
    object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (Bool, NSError) -> Void in
        //blahhh
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

}
`

Answer (score 0):

**parseClassName** is a readonly variable and is only used when subclassing PFObject.
https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/parseClassName

> The class name of the object.
>
> @property (strong, readonly) NSString *parseClassName
>
> Declared In
>   PFObject.h

Obj-C

```
@implementation MYGame

 @dynamic title;

 + (NSString *)parseClassName {
     return @"Game";
 }

 @end
```

Swift

```
class MYGame: PFObject  {
    class func parseClassName() -> String! {
        return "Game"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had used a storyboard and needed to create an `initWithCoder:` method in my `PFQueryTableViewController` subclass.  The template pointed to in the Parse.com docs lacks this method, but the first comment following the example does include an example implementation: https://gist.github.com/jamesyu/ba03c1a550f14f88f95d#gistcomment-74202

The message "**You need to specify a parseClassName for the PFQueryTableViewController**" is being generated because none of the methods are setting the `PFQueryTableViewController`'s `parseClassName` property.  You'll note that the property *is defined quite plainly* in the `initWithStyle:` method example provided in the docs.  But, that method *won't be called* if the view is loaded via a storyboard: for that you'll need to set `parseClassName` in the `initWithCoder:` method.

Also, don't confuse subclassing a `PFQueryTableViewController` for a `PFObject`.  For a PFObject you need to create a class method called `parseClassName` and also register the subclass before calling [Parse setApplicationId:aid clientKey:ckey]. You don't do those things for a PFQueryTableViewController or any of the other ParseUI view controllers.  They rely on one or more of the `init` methods.